# Is Exact Time Sync Policy the default policy for Time Synchronizer?

Tags: message-filters

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

What is the difference between the time synchronizer and the exact time sync policy under message filter. In [message_filters](http://wiki.ros.org/message_filters) does both example 4.2 and 7.2  have the same outcome?

I might have overlooked something or might not be looking at this correctly.

Thanking you,
Benny

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/173195/is-exact-time-sync-policy-the-default-policy-for-time-synchronizer?/) by [Benny](https://answers.ros.org/users/2216/benny/) on ROS Answers with karma: 132 on 2014-06-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes; they're the same.

I think this is a historical artifact; the TimeSynchronizer was probably written first, and then the policy-based synchronizer was written later, but the TimeSynchronizer was kept to preserve the existing API. If I remember correctly, the TimeSynchronizer is implemented using an exact time policy synchronizer.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-06-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Benny](https://answers.ros.org/users/2216/benny/) on 2014-06-09**:
Would you recommend using policy synchronizer over TimeSynchronizer?